# Check if user has Read/Write permissions

Tags: windows, powershell, file-permissions

I'm given the user domain\name, password and the path and I want to show if given user has write or/and read access in given directory.

General idea:

```
function Has-Read-Access {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$userLogin
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$userPwd
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$directory
    )
    $hasReadAccess = 0
    #insert magic here
    return $hasReadAccess
}

Has-Read-Access -userLogin 'DOMAIN\user' -userPwd 'Passw0rd' -directory 'C:\FolderName\'
```

I have tried running the `powershell.exe` by a different user:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential "TestDomain\Me"
```

But it seems like a wrong approach.

Comment: Please avoid re-posting questions. Improve your [existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34853336/1630171) by editing missing information into it to get it re-opened/un-downvoted. Gathering downvoted questions may eventually lead to a question ban.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easy way to see who has **Effective** access to a folder use ([PowerShellAccessControl Module 3.0/4.0](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShellAccessControl-d3be7b83)

And some code like:

```
Get-Item $directory | Get-EffectiveAccess -Principal $UserName
```

To get the list of users who have access to a folder use Get-ACL ([TechNet Article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/14/hey-scripting-guy-september-14-2009.aspx))

```
Get-ACL $Directory
```

Note: you don't need to know someone's password to get what access they have.

Comment: Note however that this presumably uses GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl which has [a number of limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637(v=vs.85).aspx).  (There isn't any comprehensive way of doing this without the user's credentials.)

Comment: Incidentally, the reason you may need someone's password to determine their access is that they may belong (directly or indirectly) to a domain group whose membership you don't have permission to see.